# Tab on user page doesnt show up

Tags: users, 7, routes

I dont know what i doing wrong but for reasons the tab on user page doesnt appear!
i have like three tabs which i place my self in custom module and they ok.. But now trying to use the principle i used nothing works. 
below is my code! Any suggestions?

```
 

$items=array();

$items['user/%user/mysite-news'] = array(
'title' =>t('Мой Новости'),
'description' => t('yo news.'),
'page callback' => 'mysite_news',
'page arguments' => array(1),
'access callback' =>array('view kupon'),
'type' =>MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);
$items['user/%user/mysite-news/my-news'] = array(
'title' =>t('Мой Новости'),
'description' => t('see your news.'),
'page callback' => 'mysite_news',
'page arguments' => array(1),
'access callback' => TRUE,
'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
'weight'=>-15,
);

//and my call back function 
function mysite_news($account){
  $my_name=t('my name is $c',array('$c'=>$account->name));
return $my_name;
}
?>
```

if i visit the link
user/1/mysite-news/my-news

the result is displayed, "my name is admin".
But the tab doesnt show on user page.. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't define the `'page callback'` for the `MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK` since it is taken care of by the 'root' page, plus without any additional tabs it won't show up anyway.  If you add another `MENU_LOCAL_TASK` it should show up.  You can think of the default local task as the page itself, there would be no reason for a VIEW tab there without anything else like EDIT UNPUBLISH etc.

Comment: Thank you for ur suggestion,now its working.The other thing is i replaced  'access callback' =>array('view kupon'); with 'access arguments' => array('view kupon').